# How to solve 'glog/logging.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, reactive-programming

I start a new project of react-native or when I install the modules At Compiling time getting error,Please Help me how to solve this issues.

Comment: Please provide more information like error details and what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for given replay sir ,'glog/logging.h' file not found issue completed my end but 
one more issue getting at runtime Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin) Please help be sir

Comment: Add your solution as an answer here, how you solved it so it may help others and for your second error please ask a new question :)

Comment: Hi Sir
First Error Solution :- 1)Please check your react-native folder in node-modules ,my end react-native not installed completely in node-modules folder 2) After i run in terminal   cd ./node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party && cd $(ls | grep 'glog' | awk '{print $1}') && ./configure  My issues fixed

Comment: Put it as answer not comment and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

I Hope this help you Please follow bellow steps:-

1)Please check your react-native installed completely or not in node-modules folder (incase not install completely please install once again)

2) Go to you root directory for system (or)project path( where your install npm in your computer path)

3) After i run in terminal `cd ./node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party && cd $(ls | grep 'glog' | awk '{print $1}') && ./configure` My issues fixed

Comment: This Solution Works for "react-native": "0.57.8"